# onBeforeUnload and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js. Is it possible to use onbeforeunload in node.js? If yes, can "no script" plugin for firefox will not block script created by node.js? I always want to notify my visitors using onbeforeunload before leaving the page with forms not yet filled up w/ necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

Node is backend code. Think of it like PHP but JavaScript.

The frontend is not aware of what language the backend is running. If a user is blocking scripts from running then all scripts, hard-coded on a page or placed there when Node renders it, will be blocked.